# std::nearbyint vs std::round in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, rounding

C++11 introduced the [std::nearbyint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nearbyint) and [std::round](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) functions. Both return the "nearest" integer value.

**When and where should I prefer one over the other?**

I have tested them with the value of `0.5`:

**Case 1** : [Demo for nearbyint](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n7117p2pfW2Izv59)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"nearbyint(0.5) = "<<std::nearbyint(0.5);
}
```

**output:** `0`

**Case 2 :** [Demo for round](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aRVsyqyn3NTyDC0Q)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"round(0.5) = "<<std::round(0.5);
}
```

**output:** `1`

Why are the outputs different?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `std::round` function ignores the [current rounding mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round) while the `std::nearbyint` takes it into account. You can change the rounding mode:

```
#include <cfenv>
int main() {
    std::fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    // perform calculations
    std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    // perform calculations
    // other rounding methods...
}
```

and observe different results. To obtain the current rounding mode value use the [std::fegetround()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround) function. Chances are the default (implementation defined) value is `0` which translates to `FE_TONEAREST`.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out in [Ron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47156959/780717), one difference between `rint()` and `nearbyint()` on one hand, and `round()` on the other hand, is that the latter uses a *fixed* rounding mode, regardless of the *dynamic* rounding mode currently in effect. The details of this cannot be found in the 2011 ISO C++ standard, which in section **26.8 C library [c.math]** simply points to the C standard. The 1999 ISO C standard specifies the operation of `round()` as follows:

> **7.12.9.6** [...] The round functions round their argument to the nearest integer value in floating-point format, rounding halfway cases away
>   from zero, regardless of the current rounding direction.

The specific rounding mode used by `round()` is listed in section **4.3.1** of the IEEE 754 (2008) floating-point standard as `roundTiesToAway`, meaning tie cases are rounded away from zero. But the usual binding of `FE_TONEAREST` is to the IEEE-754 (2008) rounding mode `roundTiesToEven`, meaning such tie cases round to an even integer. In fact, that is the **only** implementation of `FE_TONEAREST` I have ever encountered on any of numerous system platforms I have used that support `fesetround()`.

The difference in the handling of these two variants of rounding "to nearest"  is apparent in the asker's example: `0.5` rounds to the next larger (in magnitude) integer (`1`) when using `round()`, but it rounds to an even integer (`0`) when `nearbyint()` or `rint()` are used.